# How do I run ASGI alongside WSGI on Heroku with NGINX, Django, uWSGI, and Daphne?

Tags: django, nginx, heroku, channel

Something is wrong with nginx start up and connecting to websockets but I'm having trouble figuring out how to solve it. Looking at the heroku logs, the Daphne process end up getting an error "CRITICAL Listen failure: Couldn't listen on unix:/tmp/nginx.socket:48560: [Errno -2] Name or service not known." And the web process just keeps printing "buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization" every second.

Here is my code:

Procfile:

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: bin/start-nginx-debug uwsgi uwsgi.ini
daphne: daphne my_project.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind unix:/tmp/nginx.socket -v2
worker: celery -A my_project worker -l info
```

nginx.conf.erb:

```
daemon off;
# Heroku dynos have at least 4 cores.
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

events {
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS'] || 1024 %>;
}

http {
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 512;
    gzip_proxied any; # Heroku router sends Via header

    server_tokens off;

    log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
    access_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ACCESS_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/access.log' %> l2met;
    error_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ERROR_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/error.log' %>;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;

    # Must read the body in 5 seconds.
    client_body_timeout 5;

    # upstream for uWSGI
    upstream uwsgi_app {
        server unix:///tmp/nginx.socket; #unix:/app/my_project/uwsgi_app.sock; #
    }

    # upstream for Daphne
    upstream daphne {
        server unix:///tmp/nginx.socket; #unix:/app/my_project/daphne.sock; 
    }

    server {
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
        server_name _;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location / {
            # Uncomment this if statement to force SSL/redirect http -> https
            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            }

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; #//uwsgi_app; 
            #include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
            #uwsgi_pass  uwsgi_app;
        }
        location /init-nginx/ {
            internal;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
        location /ws/ {
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_redirect      off;
            proxy_pass          http://daphne;
        }
        location /static/ {
            alias /app/my_project/static/;
        }
        location /media/ {
            alias /app/my_project/media/;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the heroku-buildpack-nginx.  I think the first issue is in nginx startup.  The docs say I have to "touch /tmp/app-initialized when you are ready for traffic." How do I do that with Django?  Is there something else wrong with my setup or should it connect if I can get it to start correctly?

The WSGI part and even celery works, even with the nginx part working.  I know the static and media part is also wrong, I haven't gotten there yet...

Appreciate the help!

Comment: ever got this to work?

Comment: No, I didn't - I ended up using Daphne (ASGI) to handle both sync and async requests and not using WSGI at all, and therefore not needing NGINX to direct traffic.  It's still unclear to me whether this is really to correct way to handle it or not, but everything works now.  I might eventually migrate to AWS or similar if I need to set it up how I initially wanted to.

Comment: thank you for replying. The "problem" with Daphne is it handles a single request at a time. So asynchronous, but not parallel.